# How to use flex-htmlfilter?

Tags: apache-flex, external, flash-builder, html

I can't seem to find any sort of documentation about usage of [flex-htmlfilter](http://code.google.com/p/flex-htmlfilter/)?
Can anyone be kind enough to give me a few sample usage of it? Like, how do I use HTML codes from external pages? E.g. I want to pull the content of the flex-htmlfilter from an external php file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've found an answer by now, but the code below worked for me:

```
import com.htmlFilter.htmlFilter;
private var theHtmlFilter:htmlFilter = new htmlFilter();      

[Bindable]
private var theText:String = theHtmlFilter.filterContent("<p>nothing
important</p><ol><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li></ol>");
```

Make sure you have the flex-htmlfilter.swc in your libs folder/build path, and then import the custom htmlText component and set the text property to the string "theText."  You could pull the compatible html code from your php app and filter it using this technique.

```
xmlns:custom="com.htmlFilter.*"

<custom:htmlText id="customText"
    bottom="0"
    verticalScrollPolicy="off"
    text="{theText}"
    cssFile="styles.css"
    width="100%"/>
```

Comment: any idea how to use htmlTable tag, how to supply html text(table structure) to it???
I am trying but not getting it working at all, any help would be appreciated